# regex to extract attribute from html as text

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting following response as a string from my api

```
var responseText = '<ol><li> <a href="abc.com"></a></li><li> <a href="xyz.com"></a></li></ol>'
```

Now I want to extract only href values from a string, so I am thinking write a regex which will check get it...

I am too weak in regex

I want only `[abc.com, xyz.com]` as my output

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Minimum effort](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+extract+href+attributes+from+string+site%3Astackoverflow.com&t=ffab&ia=web) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do better than the regex for this. You can create an element, use your response as its inner HTML and then extract all `href`:

```js
const container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = responseText;
const hrefs = [...container.querySelectorAll('[href]')].map(element => element.getAttribute('href'));

console.log(hrefs); // ['abc.com', 'xyz.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

RegEx is not necessary here. Just turn the string into parsed HTML and then use the DOM API to extract the attribute value:

```js
var responseText = '<ol><li> <a href="abc.com"></a></li><li> <a href="xyz.com"></a></li></ol>';

let temp = document.createElement("div"); // Temporary container
temp.innerHTML = responseText;            // Populate with parsed HTML string

// Collect all the <a> elements into an array
let anchors = Array.prototype.slice.call(temp.querySelectorAll("a")); 

// Loop over the collection of anchors
let results = anchors.map(function(a){
   return a.getAttribute("href"); // Push the href attribute value into the results array
  //return a.href;                // Grab the href property value.
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `a.href` will return absolute `href`, so for invalid hrefs it will assume it's a relative path. I updated my answer just because of that. `a.getAttribute('href')` is the way to go in this case.

Comment: @RoboRobok Was updating the answer as you commented.

Comment: <3 Cool cool <3

Comment: Also, you don't need `Array.prototype.slice.call`. There's `Array.from()` method and of course the spread syntax.

Comment: @RoboRobok Actually you do. `.map` isn't supported on node lists returned from `querySelectorAll()` in some browsers and those same browsers don't support `Array.from` or the spread syntax either, so you must use something to convert the node list that all browsers will support.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can assume that `Array.from` and spread work. It's 2020.

Comment: @RoboRobok Except if you use any version of IE, which many companies still do.

Comment: Not sure about America, but in Europe it's certainly not the case anymore (luckily).

Comment: @RoboRobok I would disagree. I work globally and while it's certainly not what you want, many companies around the world still have proprietary applications that run in-house (not public facing) that took years, man-hours, and $$$ to develop that work as-is and therefore they continue to use IE.

Comment: I'm not gonna write poor code because of that though. In my own projects I don't care and in others I use Babel.

Comment: @RoboRobok Compatible code != Poor code.

Comment: In JavaScript, I'm afraid it kinda is...

Comment: @RoboRobok Well, agree to disagree. I've been developing and teaching JavaScript globally since it was invented, so I think I have a little understanding of it.